# Excel Charts - How do i plot time on the Y axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am a keen runner and am trying to plot my progress on a chart using the following times

```
00:27:18
00:28:19
00:26:49
00:27:19
00:26:05
00:27:18
00:26:22
00:26:49
00:30:40
00:28:03
00:26:58
00:27:35
00:26:12
00:25:24
00:25:34
00:25:15
```

However excel insists on creating a chart that runs from 0 to 36 minutes. I would like to showing times from 20 to 30 minutes only to show real differences.

Comment: You should accept one of the two answer to close this question.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your data is formatted as time (so Excel doesn't get confused), then:

1. Select your Y Axis
2. Right click, and choose Format Axis
3. Adjust your Minimum and Maximum values from Auto to your desired settings.
4. Format to your preference.

If you want nice clean minute marks (20:00, 21:00, 22:00...) you'll need to use several decimal places for your min, max and major unit values.  Here's the values I used:

- Min: 0.0138888889
- Max: 0.0208333333
- Maj: 0.0006944444

These give nice clean, even minute (no second) labels on your Y Axis.  Also, you have a value greater than 30:00, so your line will go off the chart for your 30:40 time.  Finally, using a Truncated Y Axis is fine for a line chart, but you shouldn't use it for a bar/column chart (which should always start at 0).

Answer (score 4):

Excel stores times as fractions of a day, i.e. 24 hours = value 1.

```
1 hour = 1 / 24
1 minute = 1 / (24 * 60)
1 second = 1 / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

You can calculate and use these values as min/max for your chart, e.g. `20 minutes = 20 / (24 * 60) = 0.01389` and so on..